# Why does the standard provide both is_integer and is_exact?

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, fixed-point, numeric-limits

`std::numeric_limits` provides 2 constants that are mutually exclusive:

- [`is_integer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_integer) : *"`true` for all integer arithmetic types `T`"*
- [`is_exact`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_exact): *"`true` for all arithmetic types `T` that use exact representation"*

Is there the possibility of a non-exact integral type? What is trying to be allowed for here?

In all my templates where I to know if I am dealing with precise numbers, I used `is_integer`, do I need to go add a check for `is_exact` as well now?

Comment: Fixed-point maybe? Or fractions? There is actually a comment on encppreference regarding this. You are allowed to specialize such template for your own types.

Comment: Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203654/stdnumeric-limitsis-exact-what-is-a-usable-definition) and the C++ standard, it looks like the C++ committee did not provide a good definition of `is_exact`. In integers, `7/3` does not give an exact result. It is in fact worse than floating-point `7./3.`. So integers can be said to be exact only by “defining” the `/` operation to be a truncated division, not normal mathematical division. But, if you are going to do that, then floating-point is also exact in the same way; its operations give exactly their defined results.

Comment: Perhaps a meaning of `is_exact` is “many programmers understand the arithmetic of this type.” That seems to be a major distinguishing factor between integer arithmetic and floating-point arithmetic. :-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I guess... This is clearly left in place to provide for a fixed point future type. I've started parsing through proposals. I love the idea of getting a new primitive type... things definitely look interesting!

Comment: Hmm, `is_integer` has a nice _exact_ definition.  `is_exact` definition has far more room for interpretation - not so _exact_.

Answer (score 13):

From [`is_exact`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_exact) *cppreference* page:

> **Notes**
>
> While all fundamental types T for which
> `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_exact==true` are integer types, *a library
> may define exact types that aren't integers*, e.g. a rational
> arithmetics type representing fractions.

---

And, as @Holt has mentioned, the standard describes it as well:

> 21.3.4.1 numeric_limits members [numeric.limits.members]
>
> static constexpr bool is_exact;
>
> true if the type uses an exact representation. *All integer types are exact, but not all exact types are integer. For example, rational and fixed-exponent representations are exact but not integer.*

Comment: Standard quote for this: *"All integer types are exact, but not all exact types are integer. For example, rational and fixed-exponent representations are exact but not integer."*

Comment: @Holt And now I'm scared of all the templates I've just depended on `is_integer` in :(

Comment: @JonathanMee It completely depends on what you want to check for your templates. `is_integer` is stronger than `is_exact`.

Comment: @Holt And I guess I should only be scared if I start trying to write my own types... Or if the standard implements a fixed point type... Are there any plans to implement fixed point in the standard?